# String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'image' at row 1

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When i click select some random image.then that image name is so long even
though it is varchar
My migration file

```
   $table->id();
   $table->string('image');  
   $table->timestamps();
```

This is my image uploader with image preview

```
  <form @submit.prevent= "createImage()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" v-on:change="onImageChange" class="form-control">
         <div v-if="image">
               <img :src="image" >
          </div>
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

This is script for image uploader and image preview

```
 methods:{
        onImageChange(e) {
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length)
                return;
            this.createImage(files[0]);
        },
        createImage(file) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let vm = this;
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                vm.image = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
         createImage(){
          axios.post(`imageUpload`,{
                image:this.image,
        } 
     }
```

This is my Controller using laravel image intervention but my image name is so long although it is
vachar

```
if($request->get('image'))
    {
        $image = $request->get('image');
        $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1]) 
        [1];
        \Image::make($request->get('image'))->save(public_path('backend/images/').$name);
    }
   Image::create($request->all());
```

and my image name will be like this

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your migration file for that table where you are trying to store the image?

Comment: @BelisarioPeró

yeah Sure

Answer (score 0):

If your image file name is correct, change your column in migration to `string` or `text()`

Comment: Thanks i change but still same error is coming.
when i put console.log(this.image); this tupe of error is coming

Comment: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCcUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAIAcAmcAFEs2YTl0UTBTV05EUVZkaGthVXhnHAIoAGJGQk1EMDEwMDBhYzMwMzAwMDA0ZTMyMDAwMDM0NmMwMDAwYWY3MDAwMDBkZDc1MDAwMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHRleHQAAAAARkIAAFhZWi